# Ruby scope / ActiveRecord query no-ops

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to run add a scope in Rails that kicks in only when arguments are passed into it - is there a neat way to avoid the messy `1=1` default argument?

```
scope :tagged, -> (tags) { [tags].flatten.compact.empty? ? where('1 = 1') : where("#{self.table_name}.tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", [tags].flatten.compact)}
```

Basically, what's the equivalent of `where('1=1')` inside a scope that will return the current query and allow continued chaining? Returning `self` doesn't work - it returns the object and all chains need to be constructed again from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope `all` solves your problem. Splitting up your huge on-liner into something more readable gives:

```
scope :tagged, -> (tags) do
  if [tags].flatten.compact.empty? 
    all
  else
    where(
      "#{self.table_name}.tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]",
      [tags].flatten.compact
    )
  end
end
```

However, this can be taken a step further: If a rails scope returns `nil`, then it will *implicitly* call `all` anyway! In other words, we can simply write:

```
scope :tagged, -> (tags) do
  if [tags].flatten.compact.present? 
    where(
      "#{self.table_name}.tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]",
      [tags].flatten.compact
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd also recommend, if possible, simplifying the code which calls this scope: Your call to `.flatten.compact` is a bit dodgy! Ideally, you should have more confidence in the data structures being passed between methods.

Comment: `[tags].flatten.compact` is actually really useful - it allows one to use the scope with `nil`, a single `tag` and an array of `[tags]`. More about flexibility than mistrust.

Comment: [*tags] is my preferred way to accomplish that. Does exactly what you say (also allows `[]` in addition to `nil`) and no more.

Comment: Why would you want to use a scope of `nil`? If anything, that's a sign that something has gone *wrong* elsewhere in the code (and you're hiding the error here). As for using a single tag vs an array, this is fine: You can just define the method like: `scope :tagged, -> (*tags) { where("...", tags) if tags.present? }`

Comment: That's actually a good point about nil. I don't see how the single tag will work though - is `tagged(tag)` and `tagged([tag])` the same in this case?

Comment: `*tags` is using the splat operator: http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion. This means you can call the scope with an arbitrarily long list of arguments, e.g. `tagged('one')` or `tagged('one', 'two', 'three')`. If you already have an array of tags, then you can do: `tags = ['one', 'two', 'three'] ..... tagged(*tags)`